# Prove that ${D^n(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}(n! - \int_{0}^{x}t^ne^{-t}dt)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: Prove that $$\mathbf{D^n(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}(n! - \int_{0}^{x}t^ne^{-t}dt)}$$

What I did:

Using Leibnitz formula

$$u = e^{-x} \hspace{1cm}v = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$D^nu = (-1)^ne^{-x} \hspace{1cm} D^nv = \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}\\$$

$$D^n(\frac{e^x}{x})= \frac{(-1)^nn!}{x^{n+1}}e^{-x} + \tbinom{n}{1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^{n}}De^{-x} + \tbinom{n}{2} \frac{(-1)^{n-2}(n-2)!}{x^{n-1}}D^2e^{-x} + \tbinom{n}{3} \frac{(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!}{x^{n-2}}D^3e^{-x} + ...+ \tbinom{n}{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-n}(n-n)!}{x}D^ne^{-x}$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{x^{n+1}}(e^{-x} + xe^{-x} + \frac{x^2}{2!}e^{-x} + \frac{x^3}{3!}e^{-x} + ... +\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{-x})$$

That's what I got, I don't know how to arrive at the given nth term in the question, especially the integral part. My instincts tell me that there might be a mistake in the question. Maybe it's supposed to be:

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}(n! - \int_{0}^{x}x^ne^{-x}dt)$$

Please how do I get the given nth term?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{x}t^ne^{-t}dt = x^n e^{-x} + n\int_{0}^{x}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt$

$n\int_{0}^{x}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt = nx^{n-1} e^{-x} + n(n-1)\int_{0}^{x}t^{n-2}e^{-t}dt$

do this until:

$n(n-1)...2\int_{0}^{x}te^{-t}dt = n(n-1)..2xe^{-x} + n(n-1)...2\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}dt$

Simplifying, we get the answer required.

Comment: I think you missed minus, isn't it supposed to be: 
$\int_{0}^{x}t^ne^{-t}dt = -x^n e^{-x} + n\int_{0}^{x}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt$

$n\int_{0}^{x}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt = -nx^{n-1} e^{-x} + n(n-1)\int_{0}^{x}t^{n-2}e^{-t}dt$

Comment: Also, could you please provide more steps, I'm struggling to figure out what you mean by the last line and how to arrive at the answer

Comment: the minus sign goes away as you take the limits from $0$ to $x$. On your second question, all I am saying is do the same integration by parts $n$ times until you get rid of all the $t$.

Comment: If you write down those $n$ equations, and you can add them. Stuff get cancelled and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove it using induction on $n$. So for $n=0$, we have (with the natural definition that the $0$'th derivative of a function is just the function itself) that

\begin{align*}
\frac{(-1)^0}{x^{0+1}}\left(0!-\int_0^x t^0e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)
&= \frac{1}{x}\left(1-\int_0^x e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}{t}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{x}\left(1-\biggl[-e^{-t}\biggr]_0^x\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{x}\left(1+e^{-x}-1\right) \\
&= \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}^0}{\mathrm{d}x^0}\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right),
\end{align*}

and so it holds for the base case. Now suppose it holds for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, for $n+1$, we have that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n+1}}\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right)
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n}}\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}\left(n!-\int_0^x t^ne^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\right) \\
&= -(n+1)\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+2}}\left(n!-\int_0^x t^ne^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)+\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}}x^ne^{-x} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^{n+2}}\left((n+1)!-(n+1)\int_0^x t^ne^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)-\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^{n+2}}x^{n+1}e^{-x} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^{n+2}}\left((n+1)!-x^{n+1}e^{-x}-(n+1)\int_0^x t^ne^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right) \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^{n+2}}\left((n+1)!-\left(\biggl[t^{n+1}e^{-t}\biggr]_0^x+\int_0^x (n+1)t^ne^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^{n+2}}\left((n+1)!-\int_0^x t^{n+1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right), \\
\end{align*}

and so it holds in this case as well. The result now follows by induction.